# Calling an R script with command line arguments from Python rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I want to be able to call R files from python using the rpy2 modules.
I would like to be able to pass arguments to these scripts that can be interpreted by R's commandArgs function.

So if my R script (`trivial_script.r`) looks like:

```
print(commandArgs(TRUE))
```

and my Python 2.7 script looks like:

```
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> script = robjects.r.source('trivial_script.r')
```

How can I call it from rpy2.robjects with the arguments "arg1", "arg2", "arg3" ?

Comment: Rpy2 lets one use an R script as if it was a module:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373343/passing-vectors-and-params-from-python-to-r-functions/28375231#28375231

Answer (score 5):

I see the two approaches (RPy vs command line script) as two seperate parts. If you use RPy there is no need to pass command line arguments. You simply create a function that contains the functionality you want to run in R, and call that function from Python with `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`.

If you want to use a R command line script from within Python, have a look at the [`subprocess` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) in Python. There you can call and R script from the command line using:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['Rscript', 'script.R', arg1, arg2, arg3])
```

where `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` are python objects (e.g. strings) that contain the information you want to pass to the R script.

Comment: I tend to think that I do have a need to pass command line arguments, as I am trying to use scripts that are also used in a standalone capacity.

Comment: Please @Paul can you provide an example on the first approach ? Edit : I fail to understand how that uses R language, it seems to me you are advising to create a python function that _does the same thing_ than the R function