# How do I pass an argrument to an R Script from Python using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, r

I'd like to pass a single variable to my R script while running it from python.

This is my code -

```
i = 0 

with open(result_filename, 'a') as result:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['Rscript',
                                'MyScript.R'
                                ],
                                stdout=result);
```

Here's a reproducible R example

```
#! /usr/bin/Rscript

print(i)
print(3)
```

How can I access `i` from my R Script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an R script with command line arguments from Python rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070200/calling-an-r-script-with-command-line-arguments-from-python-rpy2)

Comment: I'm unclear how `arg1`, `arg2`, etc appear in my R environment. Will they be created as variables with the names that I give them?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library in Python

You must pass the argument as a string. Then you can convert it back in your R script

**Python**:

```
import subprocess
    
i = 0 
with open(result_filename, 'a') as result: 
    output = subprocess.run(['Rscript', 'RScriptWeeklyActives.R', str(i)], stdout=result)
```

**R**:

```
#! /usr/bin/Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
i = strtoi(args[1])
print(i)
print(3)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

```
import subprocess

i = 0 

with open(result_filename, 'a') as result:
    command = subprocess.Popen(['Rscript', 'RScriptWeeklyActives.R', 'i'], stdout=result)
```

Rscript will get value 0 as a string you have to convert it to int.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me with Shell = True. You can set up the script to be print(1) and, for me, the output file is empty. When I get rid of shell = True, then the output file shows the number 1

Comment: It's unclear to me how to access the `i` variable from R